# How to visualize isolation forest algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, plot, scatter-plot, contour, isolation

I have a dataset with columns: time and ch2o. I am calculating a new column, anomaly, which has the value 0 if there isn't an anomaly in the dataset and 1 if it is. So far, I have: https://www.codepile.net/pile/k78QyXNR . I am trying to visualize the isolation forest algorithm's results, but I cannot think of some parameters to give the scatter plot which decides the contour around the scatter points. The code is working and is displaying the scatter plot and the division of planes between anomaly and not anomaly, but I have also used Decision Forest to reach this. i need to remove the decision forest algorithm and to plot only the isolation forest algorithm.
Here are the plots:
[image]
[image]